# Does the :not() pseudo-class support parent elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In CSS, can you target an element, then exclude instances of it based on parent wrapper elements higher up the DOM?

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
         <li>link</li>
         <li>link</li>
         <li>link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul>
     <li>link</li>
     <li>link</li>
     <li>link</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    color:red;
}
li:not(.wrap li) {
    colour:blue;
}
```

So in this instance, I want to exclude the first series of `<li>` tags based on their parent wrapper. Is this achievable with CSS? (and I don't mean just target `.wrap li` and apply the desired styles there, as in my case I *have to exclude*)

Comment: That's complicated. Why not just target all `li`s and make them blue. Then target the `.wrap li`, and make them red?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869061/is-the-css-not-selector-supposed-to-work-with-distant-descendants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In CSS, can you target an element, then exclude instances of it based on parent wrapper elements higher up the DOM?

No, not the way you seem to be attempting with:

```
li:not(.wrap li)
```

You could, though, use instead a more simple approach of styling all `<li>` elements, and then specifically styling those elements that are descendants of an ancestor with the `wrap` class-name:

```
li {
    /* generic styles for <li> elements */
}
.wrap li {
    /* specific styles for <li> elements that are
       descendants of elements with a class of '.wrap' */
}
```

```css
li {
  color: blue;
}
.wrap li {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
         <li>link</li>
         <li>link</li>
         <li>link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul>
     <li>link</li>
     <li>link</li>
     <li>link</li>
</ul>
```

---

Note that the following was removed from the above portion of the answer, due to its fragility - having to escape the period in the selector, and the fact that it's open to accidentally being overwritten by *any* ancestor having the `'wrap'` class-name:

```
:not(\.wrap) li
```

```css
li {
  color: red;
}
div:not(\.wrap) li {
  color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
         <li>link</li>
         <li>link</li>
         <li>link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul>
     <li>link</li>
     <li>link</li>
     <li>link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, what escaping the period in `\.wrap` really does is transform it from a class selector into a *type selector*. Since an element of one type cannot be another, this makes `div:not(\.wrap)` similar to `div:not(p)`, i.e. a guaranteed match for all div elements, albeit [with slightly increased specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299817/can-type-selectors-be-repeated-to-increase-specificity/28300471#28300471). The class attribute is completely removed from the equation. If you wrapped the second ul in its own div, the selector would match all li elements.