# How to grouply select multi elements CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I use bootstrap. Table td is padding with 8px by bootstrap. But I just need 2px padding, So I use this style sheets to make the layout.

```
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

I want to know how can I select the td more easily?
I'm **more curiously** about this way **one layer a step**.

```
.table > (thead, tbody, tfoot) > (td , th)
```

Or this: **Can the * match many layers**?

```
.table > * > td
```

Here is the snippet, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .table > thead > tr > th,
    .table > tbody > tr > th,
    .table > tfoot > tr > th,
    .table > thead > tr > td,
    .table > tbody > tr > td,
    .table > tfoot > tr > td {
      padding: 1px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: `.table > * > tr > td, .table > * > tr > th`?

Comment: @kukkuz It not works. You can check it in the snippet of my question.

Comment: I tested @kukkuz's suggestion with your snippet and it sure as hell works.

Comment: @BoltClock I just use .table > * > tr > td, .table > * > tr > th to replace my stylesheet, the td padding is also 8px. It need to add !important to make it works. In the question, there neednot the !important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS Selectors 4, there is [a functional pseudo-class `:matches`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches), that allows for such grouping:

```
.table > *:matches(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr > *:matches(th, td) { ... }
```

Unfortunately, it works currently only in Safari (Chrome and Firefox also have experimental support for its old form as `:-webkit-any()` and `:-moz-any()`, but it's not very helpful).

A single universal selector `*` can't match many levels. It's meaning is "any single element". But you can match two levels of any elements by `* > *`.

I'd suggest to use a hack for increasing specificity like this:

```css
.table > * > tr > *:not(#any-fictional-id) {
   padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- whatever... -->
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

`:not()` selector has the specificity of its argument, in this case, the specificity of ID, that is definitely higher than specificity of any classes. But you still can override it with `!important` if necessary. You can specify any fictional ID that doesn't actually exist in the markup.

Comment: I know nothing about #any-existing-id here.

Comment: I edited my answer. The point is to specify the _fictional_ ID, that doesn't actually match anything (and therefore can be matched by `:not()`).

Comment: If the selector's specificity needs only to be at parity with that of `.table > (type selector) > tr > (type selector)`, I recommend `.table > * > tr > *:not(_):not(_)` instead of an ID selector. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299817/can-type-selectors-be-repeated-to-increase-specificity/28300471#28300471

Comment: @BoltClock, I agree (although `_` as tag name looks a bit unusual). I'd even write it as `.table > :not(_) > tr > :not(_)` for readability in this case (or even as `.table > :not(span) > tr > :not(span)`, given that the structure of table descendants is quite predictable and they never are `span`s). But I assumed (possibly wrongly) that some Bootstrap classes were also to be overridden.

Comment: Oh yeah, having one :not() per compound selector looks more readable. The type selector can be anything that makes sense for the use case, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use selector as `table.table > * > tr > th, table.table > * > tr > td` to set the padding value

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .table > * > tr > th, .table > * > tr > td {
      padding: 1px !important;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This also overlay be the bootstrap, you can check it. The padding is 8px of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is why CSS pre-processors like SCSS or LESS are used. To more functionally represent your code in a better syntactic way i.e to do more and to write less.

The SCSS version of what you want would be:

```
table {
  thead,  tbody, tfoot {
    tr {
      td, th {
        padding: 2px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>thead>tr>th{
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation bro,

Comment: This way can make select td or more selector easly by css

Comment: @bub: Good Lord, more than *half* of these answers are "try this" answers. Unbelievable.

Comment: @BoltClock sadly yes, but I had to review this answer

Comment: @bub: I appreciate you taking the time to leave a context-appropriate comment instead of just choosing "This does not provide an answer to the question." and moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.table td {
  padding:2px !important;
}
```

If you want the "th" also to have px padding then

```
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.table td, .table th {
  padding:2px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can try like this way**

```
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: can you make fork the snippet of my qustion, and check your answer?