# The meaning of underscore in :not(_)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using `:not()` pseudoclass this way:

```
:not(_)
```

to increase the specificity of my selector. It does its job but I would like to know what is the meaning of this underscore and what impact on specificity (0,0,0) it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple [Type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors), just one you're unlikely to find in normal circumstances.

```js
var el = document.createElement('_');
document.body.append(el);
el.textContent = 'Hello';
```

```css
_{ color: green; }
```

```html
Say
```

Moreover when `<_>` markup wouldn't be valid.

```html
<_>hello</_>
```

Comment: Thanks, in such case it will have (0,0,1) specificity and I could use for example `:not(p)` if the element I want to select is not a paragraph. As you mentioned  `_` is unlikely to be found and that's the reason `:not(_)` was used - it almost never has any effect other than increasing specificity.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk you can also increase the specificity using a random ID selector `:not(#sp_r84dt5)`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is great advice, I initially intended to ask about a better way than multiple `:not(.random-class)`, this solves my problem entirely, I feel so stupid now!

Comment: @Ryszard Jędraszyk: That's the idea, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299817/can-type-selectors-be-repeated-to-increase-specificity/28300471#28300471